# Null value in array-flattening recursion using `for` vs `slice`: why are the returns of these two functions different?

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, interpreter

Below I have provided two code snippets which, in my mind, ought to do the same thing. In the first snippet I get a "null" value. I imagine this is because a `null` value is passed into the function as `arr` when I call `steamrollArray(arr[0])` on `[]`, pushing the null value into the accumulator.

What I don't know, and I'm hoping I can have some help with, is what might be an elegant way to avoid this particular issue?

I'd like both functions to give the same output when given the same input.

As an ancillary point: I would be interested to know if anyone could point me to a method of bench-marking these two methods against one another - this is something I know nothing about, beyond the fact that it's "a thing," and it would be helpful for me generally to understand how to do such a thing, and specifically how one might do so with this problem.

As another ancillary point: is there a interactive javascript interpreter, in the same way that you can get an interactive python interpreter (where you can play with / test things in the command line)?

## **Version 1**: "natural"  recursion - returns `[1,null,2,3]`

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  //recursive (is an array)
  var accum = [];
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    accum = accum.concat(steamrollArray(arr[0]));
    if (arr.length > 1) {
      accum = accum.concat(steamrollArray(arr.slice(1)));
    }
  } else {
    accum.push(arr);
  }
  return accum;
}

console.log(
  steamrollArray([1, [], [3, [[4]]]])
);
```

## Version 2: `for` loop  recursion - returns `[1,2,3]`

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
  // I'm a steamroller, baby
  //recursive (is an array)
  var accum = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      accum = accum.concat(steamrollArray(arr[i]));
    } else {
      accum.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return accum;
}

console.log(
  steamrollArray([1, [], [3, [[4]]]])
);
```

Comment: "*is there a interactive javascript interpreter*" -- have you tried pressing `F12` in your browser? `:)` (In Chrome, you may need to click the `Console` tab.)

Comment: @apsillers exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I knew there had to be a feature like that in chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **version 1** you are pushing `arr[0]` without checking if there is an element inside `arr[0]`. So at the second call to `steamrollArray` where you are passing an empty array `[]`, `arr[0]` will be undefined:

```js
var arr = [];

console.log(arr[0]);
```

Why this isn't happening in **version 2**? It's because you have a `for` loop wrapping the `push` calls (`for(var i = 0; i < arr.length...`). So when the empty array is passed, the `for` loop is never entered. because `0 < 0` is `false`.

You can fix **version 1** by wrapping the `push` call inside an if statement like this: (the push will happen when `steamrollArray` get called with the argument `arr[0]`)

```
if(arr.length) // if length is not 0
    accum = accum.concat(steamrollArray(arr[0]));
```

**Ancillary 2:** [**NodeJs**](https://nodejs.org/en/) is a great javascript runtime. It comes with a command line interface. Try it!